# How do I control what gets posted on the RSS Feed and Custom Feeds

Tags: rss

I have a custom plugin I made to generate sales tables. It's just a form where you input a table shortcode, and the date.

I have a created a new rss feed just for this information.

What hooks can I use to display on my custom feed "A new table has been posted for 1/1/2016", each time someone submits a table?

The name of my custom feed is 'sales'.

Comment: May you please [`edit`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/243381/edit) your question ane elaborate and include you code?